# Selenium is flying through the program and not waiting for data to appear

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, range, wait

No matter what kind of waits, EC, sleeps I put in I can't get it to slow down enough to register my inventory.

The problem that happens is the script does the input of 99. Then it skips back to L or large before the inventory can register. So it goes to Large finishes that part then goes to 1X then before it can register the inventory it goes back to Large, then to 2X and again before it can register the inventor it goes back to Large again before it continues to 3x.

```
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from lxml import html

from time import sleep

import time

import csv

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www.rosegal.com/plus-size-tops-120/')

driver.maximize_window()

# This is for pagination.
for x in range(1, 60)

    # This is for the rows the produt is on.
    for r in range(1, 15):
        
        # This is for the product it's on the rows.
        for m in range(1,4):
            sleep(2) 
            # This resets the page of products   
            driver.get(f"https://www.rosegal.com/plus-size-tops-120/{x}.html")
            a = ActionChains(driver)
            product = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/ul[{r}]/li[{m}]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/a[1]')
            a.move_to_element(product ).click().perform()
            sleep(1)
            title= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h1[1]").text
            price= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[contains(@class,'my_shop_price')]").text
            # This clicks the decscription button that causes the description list to show.
            description= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page"]/section/div/div[2]/div[9]/ul/li[2]').click()
            sleep(2)
            material= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'xxkkk20')]").text

            # This controls the color choice. There could be 1 to 5 colors for a product
            for c in range(1, 5):
                # Since there could be 1 to 5 colors to chose from this try is a simple way the do the colors.
                try:
                    
                    # This calls up the different colors.
                    pat1= driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="select-attr-0"]/a[{c}]').click()
                    color1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".logsss_event_cl.itemAttr.current").get_attribute("data-value")
                    #link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".logsss_event_cl.itemAttr.current>img").get_attribute("src")
                    print(color1)
                    
                    # This for s selects the SIZE.
                    for s in range(1, 8):
                        
                        # Since there could be 6 to 8 sizes this try checks for them.
                        try:
                            
                            # This calls up the different sizes.              
                            Size_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="select-attr-1"]/span[2]/a[{s}]').click()
                            
                            image4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[1]').get_attribute("data-bigimg")
                            image4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[2]').get_attribute("data-bigimg")
                            image4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[3]').get_attribute("data-bigimg")
                            
                            # Since there can be a forth image, this try takes care of this.
                            try:
                                image4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="goods_thumb_content"]/ul/li[4]').get_attribute("data-bigimg")
                            except:
                                pass
                            size = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//body[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/span[2]/a[{s}]').text  
                            sku = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_addToCart"]').get_attribute("data-goods-sn")
                            
                            ####### This where the problem startsdatetime #######
                            
                            # First you put in a high number in the QTY input box.                
                            input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'fl num logsss_event_cl')]").send_keys('99')
                            
                            #Then you hit the Plus sign.
                            plus = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-attr-1"]/span[2]/a[1]').click()
                            sleep(8)
    
                            # Then the true inventory shows up.
                            inventory = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'fl num logsss_event_cl')]"). get_attribute("value")
                            
                            ##### The problem happens is the script does the input of 99. Then it skip back to L or large before the inventory can register
                            ##### So it goes to Large finishes that part then goes to 1X then before it can register the inventpry it's goes back to Large, then to 
                            ##### 2X and again before it can register the inventor it goes back to Large again before it continues to 3x.
                            sleep(8)
                            print(sku,  size, inventory)    
                        
                            
                        except:
                            pass
                        
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: Sorry about the code I couldn't get it to act right.

Comment: After you get the SKU variable, did you add implicit wait? Asking as your code is not showing the wait you have added.

Comment: Yes, I tried implicit wait, expect waits, I even made some up. nothing worked. Give me one to try I'd be glad to.  I still for the life of me can't see why it goes back to large size every time. I've used lots of for range statments and this is the first time I've had it do this. Is my logic off?

Comment: how many seconds were you waiting when you added the implicit wait?

Comment: I would use 8 to 30 I even tried 40.

Comment: You should wait a little longer for all the items to refresh and populate

Comment: I increase the wait time and it still just flys through.

Comment: I there anything I can do to slow it down?

Comment: After the first cycle in the for s in range((1, 8) it ignores the waits and goes too fast to record.

Comment: I took all the try: and except: out. I read where they cancel out your waits. Did change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I took all the try: and except: out of that section and the sleeps worked. Apparently sleeps and try: don't go together.

**Thanks for all your help**